# create a link that when click opens some text on the same webpage

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dreamweaver

hi i am new to html and do not know any php or javascript. I have a simple html webpage with a picture in the middle. I want it so that when you click the picture text appears describing what the picture is but without going to a new webpage. is this possible to do on just html without using javascript or php and if so how is it done? thanks

Comment: To do that you'll need Javascript at least.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do something similar with the `details` and `summary` HTML5 elements.

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HuxGT/1/) (Works only in Chrome/Safari/Opera)

```
<details>
    <summary><img src="image-source"> Click here for more information</summary>
    <p>more information</p>
</details>
```

Due to the lack of browser support, I would not recommend using them. See [**caniuse.com - summary**](http://caniuse.com/#search=summary)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the HTML title tag. The text you wanted to appear would show up on mouseOver on all browsers.

```
<img src="xxxxxx" title="This is the title" />
```

Check out on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alwaysplay/wjhES/)